# preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'w' in /var/www/.../public_html/

Tags: preg-replace

I habe a problems with PHP 5.3 and Joomla and error show like this
 preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'w' in /var/www/

My code

```
$params  = $this->item->params;
$images = json_decode($this->item->images);
$urls = json_decode($this->item->urls);
$canEdit    = $this->item->params->get('access-edit');
$user       = JFactory::getUser();

$imagesJson = json_decode($this->item->images);
$images_stringPath = substr($imagesJson->image_fulltext, 0,strripos($imagesJson->image_fulltext, '/'));
$path = "/".$images_stringPath;



$tmp_filename=preg_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$path.'/','',$value);
```

Comment: Why don’t you use `str_replace`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for simple string replacement is overkill. Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead.

Anyhow, `preg_replace()` expects a *regular expression pattern* surrounded by "delimiters", which you didn't provide.

To go into detail, this is how your function call looks:

```
$tmp = preg_replace('/var/www/.../', '', $value);
//                   ^   ^^
//                   |   ||
//                   |   |+--- "modifier"
//                   |   +---- terminating delimiter
//                   +-------- starting delimiter
```

The *starting delimiter* would be the forward slash `/`. Which terminates the pattern after `var`. After the terminating delimiter, `preg_replace()` allows for [optional modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). `w` is none of them.